# yodlee oAuth java tool errors

Tags: yodlee

I'm trying to use the Yodlee oAuth tool to build an oAuth string to launch the FastLink/LAW tool.  I have the URL provided by my customer service rep, as well as a bevy of tokens and things (which seem to have conflicting names, which is quite tricky.)

I'm trying to use the oAuth java tool.  I've installed Tomcat and the "law-tool-sourcecode" tool, but after putting in all the settings i can find (both those in the LAW-OAuth-Tool-configuration.txt file and in the various emails I've gotten from my sales rep) I get the following error message when I click "Cobrand Login", which appears to be the first step:
     Output Section: Retrieved following Result..
     Event ID: 18 ,  TimeStamp: 30/07/13 10:34:29
     java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: nullnull

Does that sound like a configuration error on my java oAuth tool?

Follow-up.  I've pulled the logfile from Tomcat, and here's the stacktrace to that exception:
javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: nullnull
    at com.yodlee.soap.core.login.cobrandlogin.CobrandLoginServiceLocator.getCobrandLoginService(Unknown Source)
    at com.sdkee.callsdk.CallSDKDelegator.loginCobrand(CallSDKDelegator.java:77)
    at com.sdkee.callsdk.CallSDKAction.loginAsCobrand(CallSDKAction.java:93)
    at com.sdkee.callsdk.CallSDKAction.execute(CallSDKAction.java:41)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a possible configuration problem with your deployment. You'll need to contact Yodlee Customer Care or your account rep so that we can collect other identifying information to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not provided the correct URL to connect to Yodlee SDK.

When you launch the LAW OAUTH Tool there is a tab in right hand corner for settings. You need to click that tab and fill in the details and then try again.

If you are not sure what details you need to fill please check with the your customer service rep.